# Angular 1.5. How to make transcluded template to bind to component scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components, transclusion

I'm using form component with common validation and saving functions. 
Inputs are passed to form as transcluded template, like so:

```
<form-editor entity="vm.entity">
        <input ng-model="vm.dirtyEntity.name" required name="nameInput">
</form-editor>
```

The problem is, ng-model is creating dirtyEntity field in parent vm, instead of modifying the components one.
Defining components controller as "formVm" didn't help.

Is there way to force transcluded element ng-model to change only component's scope?

Or is it considered incorrect to interact between transcluded template and component controller, and shouldn't be never done?

Comment: Try to manually transclude contents in proper scope.

Comment: do you mean DOM manipulation with $compile?

Comment: No, I mean `$transclude` function. I started checking this idea, but this way validation stopped working, which is not good. http://plnkr.co/edit/j5xtGBJh2iPCK0H7aB51?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Building on the plunkr of dfsq, here is a solution to your problem:

In your component, you programmatically copy the elements meant for transclusion and add them to your form controller.

You can programmatically transclude using the $transclude service and append the elements to the form like this:

```
$transclude($scope, function(clone) {
  $element.find('form').append(clone);
})
```

Then you add the elements to your form controller like this:

```
$scope.testForm.$addControl($element);
```

In this case you need to wrap it in a timeout otherwise angular will instantiate your controller and your code will run, however, the form controller is not instantiated yet.

Here is the complete snippet and you can find a plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XLlPOj8sFs6T9K8OP1rN?p=preview)

```
controller($scope, $element, $transclude, $timeout) {
  // use a timeout to break javascript flow to allow a DOM update
  $timeout(function() {
    $transclude($scope, function(clone) {
      $element.find('form').append(clone);

      // take the form and add the elements to it
      $scope.testForm.$addControl($element);
    })
  })
}
```

However, keep in mind that you might need to check for elements that are not inputs. I am unsure how robust the form controller reacts to an image added as a control.